# How to count the number of lines that contain only one comma separated and ignore count the lines with two comma separated in text file

Tags: python

I want to count the number of lines that contain only one comma-separated and ignore count the lines with two comma-separated in a text file

Below is my code

```
def countLines(filename):
   with open(filename,'r') as f: 
      CoList = f.split("\n") 
      Counter = 0 
      for i in CoList: 
          if i: 
             Counter += 1 
      return CoList

countLines('demo.txt')
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific as to what you mean by one comma separated and two comma separated? maybe give an example of sorts to demonstrate what exactly you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want?

```
def countLines(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as f: 
        Counter = 0 
        for line in f: 
            if line.count(',') == 1:
                Counter += 1 
      return Counter
```